# Converting a String into String[] of its individual character

Tags: java, string

How to convert a String into the String array,suppose there is a String **str="name"** and i want to convert into String[] which contain every element of String,i can convert into character [] but i want it in the String[]

```
   String[] tokens=str.toLowercase().split("?");
```

what should be the regex to convert it into String array so that tokens[0]="n",tokens[1]="a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already something very similar to what you want to do built in to `String`.  It's called `toCharArray()`

But, this won't do the same thing you want to do, because it will return a `char[]`.  To convert that into a `String[]` you can use this:

```
    char[] chars = "name".toCharArray();
    String[] strings = new String[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir for your ans but,how we can achieve this through regex?

Answer (score 2):

Use direct method

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

and use each `char`

Comment: i want String[] not char[]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with a regex, you can use a non capturing group:

```
String name = "name";
String[] letters = name.split("(?<=.)");
System.out.println("letters = " + Arrays.toString(letters));
```

prints `letters = [n, a, m, e]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better understanding and do it by yourself manually(although not optimal):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length())
    newChars[i] = str.charAt(i);
```

With `newChars` being of type `char[]`

Answer (score 0):

Convert string into char array, iterate through the array and convert each character into string and store it in string array.